# Slime substance containing collagen, used as glue

Tags: science-based, humans

In my world, hagfish-like creatures live near the coast, and they produce a slime substance with their bodies, containing collagen. How can that substance be used as glue by aboriginal humans? The glue may be used for crafting and repairing.

Comment: Questions should have a clear defined scope. Your question is open ended, with no guidance on how you will choose an answer over another

Comment: @L.Dutch The question is about what other scope can slimes have other than stress relief or massage devices. I don't see any problem with it. For instance, it's entirely factual that certain substances can be used for specific needs, and the same applies for this.

Comment: Read our [help]: your question must include restrictions/requirements: What will make one answer better than another? If any answer is equally effective your question is not properly constrained.

Comment: It would help a lot if you were to give us some worldbuilding context, what relevance does the question have in your society/in your world?

Comment: All your edits keep leaving this as a brainstorming type of request.

Comment: Slime as such is not a glue. Glues need some "hold together" capability as well as structural strength to stay where placed. Thus, the only way would be if the slime dried out into something that could be a glue. If the humans are living in houses on stilts, the place is likely to be so humid that any slime won't dry out. In other words, you need to rethink the idea.

Comment: You might consider posting this in the [Sand Box](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).

Comment: I'm thinking you just need to clarify that you are asking (presumably) "what kind of naturally produced substance, by a real-world-style slime creature, could be used as wood glue". Clearly we do produce glue from animal substances. Historically, we have used fish, egg whites, and, of course, hooves. I don't really know what properties the substance needs but I suspect that's the root of your question.

Comment: This actually has a legitimate answer, and is not opinion based. Slimes contain collagen. Snails are "milked" for their slime to use in beauty creams because the collagen in their slime is really good for skin. Collagen is also the active component in hide glue, which is a very strong glue generally made from hide, bones, and tissues of animals, BUT other collagen sources could be used. So a hag-fish like creature that excretes collagen rich slime would be perfect for glue making. This question should not have been closed as opinion based.

Comment: @JamieB The properties of the substance are collagen, which is found in those things, and also in slimes. It's ok that you didn't know that, as I didn't know it until I did 1 minute of searching to answer the question.

Comment: *If* they contain collagen, @AndyD273 The question was not at all specific about the composition of the slime from these "hagfish-like creatures". Oh, and really? There's an actual job-title of snail milker? We live on the weirdest planet.

Comment: @AngryMuppet To be fair to the OP, if they knew about collagen being used in glue, then they probably wouldn't have had to ask the question at all. But just because they, or you, don't know about it doesn't mean that no one does. Also, yes we do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hbenumAaJM

Comment: Wow. Even snail caviar. Thanks for that revelatory glimpse of rural Italian life, quite an eye-opener. @AndyD273 Genuinely surprised at how collagen turns-up in so many places. Must look into the properties more.

Comment: Just a note: Wooden houses, on stilts or not on stilts, are not held together by glue and have never been held together by glue. I have no idea what the question means by *"glueing the trunks of the buildings"*.

Comment: @AlexP I have specified that they are held by glue in my world.

Comment: The question does not include any such specification; and it wouldn't work anyway. Collagen-based glues are the opposite of water-resistant. Waterproof glues require advanced chemistry and have only been invented in the 19th century.

Comment: it's called hot glue, carpenters have been using it since before Jesus.

Comment: Here is an existing fish glue that is used to glue wood. Glued-together wood is used in buildings, not necessarily fish glue though, but the idea should be feasible.. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Liquid-Organic-Natural-Hermann-Sachse/dp/B00B0CQGNM

Comment: At this point, the question is a clear "how can that slime be used as a glue?". That seems objectively answerable (especially since some of the comments here already have answered it).

Comment: Google "collagen glue" it is already a real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ancient kind of glue that has been in use as a wood glue since at least ancient Egypt called hide glue, due to it historically being made from the hide and bones of animals, which are high in collagen. Collagen is also what makes gelatin jiggly.

However, animal hides are not the only source of collagen.
Slimes and mucus from snails and other creatures are also very high in Collagen, and there is no reason why it couldn't be turned into a glue.

Here's a video of someone making hide glue using deer hide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVF1Hvd0Zn0
Basically the hide is cut up and boiled for a very long time to release the collagen.

The next step is to strain out the solid matter like hide, bone, cartilage, etc. and then boil it down further until it reaches the consistency of a thick paste.

For a slime based glue, it should be very similar, except that you wouldn't have to strain out any solids as it's all just goo.
If you really wanted to you could also have them throw in stuff like fish bones or whatever to add a few more details, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks mate. Therefore the process of making the glue is the same as for hide glue?

Comment: @lollo259 I added a bit more detail. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Put the glue on one thing. Push the thing into another thing you want stuck to the first thing. Hold it in place until the glue dries enough that if holds itself. Leave the glue to dry fully.

Comment: I see what you did there 